# Eclipse and Tomcat Deployment: Always have to clean Projects after changing code

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, log4j

At work i am dreaded to work with eclipse and tomcat and for some time and different eclipse versions i got some seriously annoying issues while developing: When tomcat is running and i change code, even just one line, i have to stop tomcat, clean all projects and start it again. If i don't clean my projects tomcat refuses to start giving tons of errors like this:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MyApp]]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MyApp]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Logger
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:3297)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:2371)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:989)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Logger
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
    ... 40 more
```

It always refers to a class "Logger" which probably refers to Log4j, which i am using in all of my apps. Of course the dependencies are properly defined in my project, thats why everything works again after cleaning. However i haven't found anything to this problem on the net and it is bugging me although i tried using different eclipse versions and recrated my workspace.

Does anyone have an idea what to do about this?

Comment: *How* are the dependencies "properly defined"?

Comment: Well, all the libs im using, including log4j, are situated in my project under WebContent/WEB-INF/lib and all appear in my build path settings unter Web App Libraries. Apart from that, as i said, my app works after cleaning the project - so i guess it cannot be a general problem of my setup...

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` has a message that indicates the **fully qualified** name of the class that is missing. Hence either you have a class `Logger` in the default package (packaged classes can not see it) or you have a missing import statement.

Comment: As i said, after cleaning my projects everything works normally. So it cannot be a general problem with my code and of course i do not have any compile errors highlighted by eclipse. The problem looks like something is out of sync with my workspace or with my projects, but i cannot track down what exactly causes the problem.